# Identifying different users in shopping cart table in database before customer login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm planning to create a shopping cart. I have created a shopping cart table in my database and I'm adding products to it. Product info is stored in Products table having product price,id etc and customer table having info such as customerID,username,password etc. If i have only one shopping cart table and multiple users are trying to purchase product simultaneously, how can I determine which set of products belong to which user. I want to do this before customer can login(just like amazon which shows items in shopping cart before being logged in). Because if i have some parameter to uniquely identify user before login, when I actually login, I can add my customerID corresponding to that field.

One idea that came in my mind is to use SESSIONID and store in shopping cart table. When person is ordering many products, his sessionID would remain same before expire and after he logs in, I can add my customerID.

Any suggestions please...

Thanks.

Comment: Don't store the cart in the database; just store it in a PHP session variable?

Comment: The SESSIONID sounds like a fine idea.